# Orbeon- Setting up a DBService

Tags: jndi, orbeon

I have read all the Orbeon documentation I can find and I am still stuck on the DB access stuff.

1. I have created a field using the “Text Output”  wiget. And gave it the name of DBData.
2. I then created a DBservice called orbeon_data_load using the JNDI “orbeondb” as defined in our configuration.
3. Finally I created an action called “DataFromDB” , that on the "form-load" event, should populate the “Text Output”  widget I named DBData.
4. I’m not sure how to debug this.

Comment: Is your question "how to debug a database service with Orbeon Form Builder"? Or do you have some specific code to share?

Comment: Kevin, I am posting your comment as an answer, to follow the question-answer format of Stack Overflow. In the future, if you find an answer to your own question, feel free to post an answer yourself, as this might help other people stumbling on the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the issue was caused by an incorrect JNDI name.